# How to inject an interface implementation based on annotations at runtime using Google Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have the following scenario:

```
public interface ServiceClientAdapter {
    SomeData getSomeData()
}

@LegacyServiceClientAdapter
public class MyLegacyServiceClientAdapterImpl implements ServiceClientAdapter {
    public SomeData getSomeData() {
        // implementation          
    }
}

@NewServiceClientAdapter
public class MyNewServiceClientAdapterImpl implements ServiceClientAdapter  {
    public SomeData getSomeData() {
        // implementation          
    }    
}

public class BusinessLogic {
    @Inject
    private ServiceClientAdapter serviceClientAdapter;
}
```

LegacyServiceClientAdapter and NewServiceClientAdapter are custom annotations.

The implementation for the serviceClientAdapter field will be determined at runtime by whether the user has been migrated from the legacy to the new service or not.

What is the best way to accomplish this dependency injection using Google Guice?

Take into account that different BusinessLogic classes will exist, each with their own (different) ServiceClientAdapter-like interface and corresponding legacy and new implementation classes.

Ideally this should be done with a piece of framework code that can be used across all use cases.

Comment: How is the determination made as to whether or not the user has migrated?  Is a system property inspected or something else?

Comment: It will be determined through a call to an LDAP server (that will be cached afterwards).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the result of your LDAP call can be represented as a string, let's say `"legacy"` or `"new"`.  If not, hopefully you should still be able to adapt this example.

In your module, use a [MapBinder](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Multibindings):

```
public class BusinessLogicModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        // create empty map binder
        MapBinder<String, ServiceClientAdapter> mapBinder =
                MapBinder.newMapBinder(
                        binder(), String.class, ServiceClientAdapter.class);

        // bind different impls, keyed by descriptive strings
        mapBinder.addBinding("legacy")
                .to(MyLegacyServiceClientAdapterImpl.class);
        mapBinder.addBinding("new")
                .to(MyNewServiceClientAdapterImpl.class);
    }
}
```

Now you can inject a map of instances (or a map of providers of instances if you need to keep creating new instances) into your main class and use the string discovered at runtime to control which kind of instance you get.

```
public class BusinessLogic {
    @Inject
    private ServiceClientAdapter serviceClientAdapter;

    @Inject
    private Map<String, ServiceClientAdapter> mapBinder;

    public void setupAndUseClientAdapter() {
        String userType = getUserTypeFromLdapServer();
        serviceClientAdapter = mapBinder.get(userType);
        if (serviceClientAdapter == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "No service client adapter available for " +
                    userType + " user type.";
        }
        doStuffWithServiceClientAdapter();
    }
}
```

Comment: Busy implementing this in a generic fashion, but getting the following error: java.util.Map<mypackage.AdapterImplType, T> cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified. Should I ensure that all the serviceClientAdapters implement a root interface? Or is there some way of using TypeLiteral to allow the generic?

Comment: And what about a Provider class instead of the MapBinder that contains the call to the LDAP server?

Comment: @rudolfv I cannot guess as to where that Map error is coming from without seeing your code, especially since I'm not sure why you're trying to use the Impl class as a key to the map.

Comment: @rudolfv The MapBinder does not contain a call to the LDAP server, it contains a map of what decision to make based on the result of that call.  If you want to use an impl provider in your class, just `@Inject Map<String, Provider<ServiceClientAdapter>> mapBinder` instead of what I have above, and call `mapBinder.get(userType).get()` instead to get a clean instance.  No changes to module needed.

Comment: The key is AdapterImplType which is an enum. But I agree, too tricky for you to lend a hand without seeing the code. I managed to get a working solution up and running, with just a Provider and without MapBinder. The reason for this is that I'm running Weblogic 10.3.6 EJB's (J2EE 5) which forces me to bootstrap Guice in a certain way. I also have a constraint in that I want the LDAP lookup code in a central place and not be something implementers of the BusinessLogic EJB's should even know about. I can create a Git repo if you want to have a look?

Comment: I'm marking your answer as correct as it would be the most correct solution given my initial problem statement.

Comment: Got it.  Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) of current setup in original question if help is still needed.